# webkit slide in and slide out a page

Tags: animation, css, webkit

I'm new to webkit animations and I have been trying out to do this kind of animation 
http://demo.jeffrey-way.com/tutsMobile/#site.php?siteName=psdtuts
If you click the list element you will see page sliding in and sliding out.

I want to implement this animation to my app which is built with backbone.js, underscore.js, zepto.js 
I could use jqTouch or jquery mobile but I would like to make it as light weight as possible, because I'm building it only for IOS. So thats way I wan't to implement it by my self.

Any hints to make this implementation or should I go with jqTouch?

Answer (score 0):

In this example, there is some sort of (I hate to be vague...) ajax based content loading system. Take a look at the source:

```
<div data-role="page" id="article.php?siteName=psdtuts&amp;origLink=http%3A%2F%2Fpsd.tutsplus.com%2F%3Fp%3D15026" class="ui-page ui-body-c">
```

When you first visit, that div doesn't exist. It's created by javascript when content is required, then filled with that content, then translated (animated) into the viewport.

Here is a step by step, deduced from a quick look at the page:

1. Base page is loaded, including css, javascript, nav list
2. Script is waiting for a nav item to be clicked.
3. Upon clicking, an ajax request is made to the content corresponding to the clicked item; determined by `href="article.php?siteName=psdtuts&origLink=http://psd.tutsplus.com/?p=15081"`. My guess? This ajax request is getting content from the same place as psdtuts.com, likely in a database.
4. While that stuff is loading, javascript shows a loading animation. When loading is complete, it's hidden again.
5. Once the new content-filled div is created, it is given a default position with its left edge placed right outside of the right edge of the screen. Upon the event of being positioned, javascript then determines the view's dimensions and translates the div across the horizontal dimension. At the same time, the nav list is moved the same direction and distance.
6. When back is clicked, the view's dimensions are determined again (In case the window size changed) and the nav and content are translated to the right, hiding the content and showing the navigation again.
7. Repeat

I could be off from how this exact sample is being done, but... Well, this would work.

You wouldn't be *that* crazy to use a framework for something like this, but I can understand wanting to do a custom job. It would certainly be faster for users, but slower for you. Depending on your intent, that would be just fine.

edit: If you're only serving this to users with webkit, using a framework is even less necessary... If you're not worrying about cross browser support, there's really not a lot going on here that you couldn't accomplish easily with raw javascript.

The only reason I use jQuery for example, most of the time, is to ensure things work alright in most use cases. It just smooths so many things out... Even if 95% of the framework isn't being utilized, it's worth it when you've got a deadline.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm building the app only for iphone so thats why it would be great to implement only the animation. Do you know good source where the explain this animation?

Comment: In that case it would probably be best to use css3 to animate the pages. It would be quite a bit smoother. I'm not sure how you'd go about it... I suppose you'd position the pages as I described using javascript, then slide them in with css. Let me look into it... Maybe I can toss a jsfiddle together.

Answer (score 0):

I founded out one good example
http://andrew.hedges.name/blog/2009/05/29/animating-your-iphone-web-application